# Print only topic name using LDA with python

Tags: python-3.x, nltk, gensim, lda, stemming

I need to print only the topic word (only one word). But it contains some number, But I can not get only the topic name like "Happy". My String word is "Happy", why it shows "Happi"

```
    import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings(action='ignore', category=UserWarning, module='gensim')
from nltk.tokenize import RegexpTokenizer
from stop_words import get_stop_words
from nltk.stem.porter import PorterStemmer
from gensim import corpora, models

import gensim
import string
tokenizer = RegexpTokenizer(r'\w+')
en_stop = get_stop_words('en')
p_stemmer = PorterStemmer()
fr = open('Happy DespicableMe.txt','r')
doc_a = fr.read()
fr.close()
doc_set = [doc_a]
texts = []
for i in doc_set:


    raw = i.lower()
    tokens = tokenizer.tokenize(raw)


    stopped_tokens = [i for i in tokens if not i in en_stop]


    stemmed_tokens = [p_stemmer.stem(i) for i in stopped_tokens]


    texts.append(stemmed_tokens)


dictionary = corpora.Dictionary(texts)


corpus = [dictionary.doc2bow(text) for text in texts]


ldamodel = gensim.models.ldamodel.LdaModel(corpus, num_topics=1, id2word = dictionary, passes=20)



rafa = ldamodel.show_topics(num_topics=1, num_words=1, log=False , formatted=False)


print(rafa)
```

It only shows [(0, '0.142*"happi"')]. But I want to print only the word.

[image: Strings on the File]

Comment: Paste the content of .txt file.

Comment: It's containing lyrics of a song.

Comment: @S.Kablar updated

Comment: Was this answer helpful for your?

Answer (score 1):

You are plagued by a misunderstanding:

Stemming extracts the stem of a word through a series of transformation rules stripping off common suffixes and prefixes. Indeed, the resulting stem is not necessarily an actual English word. The purpose use of stemming is to normalize words for comparison. E.g.

```
stem_word('happy') == stem_word('happier')
```

What you need is a Lemmatizer (e.g. [nltk.stem.wordnet](http://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/stem/wordnet.html)) to lookup lemmas. Lemmas differ from stems in that a lemma is a canonical form of the word, while a stem may not be a real word.

After you have [install the corpus/wordnet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22202937/8291949) you can use it like this:

```
from nltk.corpus import wordnet
syns = wordnet.synsets("happier")
print(syns[0].lemmas()[0].name())
```

Output:

```
happy
```

Comment: Is there any way to get the actual word.

Comment: @Rafi yes, added that.